# Java: How to properly remove a value from a HashMap NOT based on the key

Tags: java, android, hashmap, set

I have a `Singleton` class that inside has a HashMap. The HashMap is made of `String` and `Set<String>`:

```
private Map<String, Set<String>> mMap = new HashMap<>();
```

What I want to achieve?

Remove a given item from all the `Set` values inside the `Map`. For example:

```
mMap.put(keyName, new HashSet<String>())
....
mViewsSwipeStates.get(keyName).add("1");
mViewsSwipeStates.get(keyName).add("2");
mViewsSwipeStates.get(keyName).add("3");
....
//Remove an item from the set 
 mMap.values().remove("3"); //Does not work
```

What is the correct way to remove an item from inside the `Set`?

Comment: You need to get the item from the map first: mViewsSwipeStates.get(keyName).remove(productCode);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to remove `productCode` from all the values of the `Map` (and not just from the value of a specific key).

You have to iterate over all the values of the `Map`, and remove from each of them the required element :

```
mMap.values().forEach(v->v.remove(productCode));
```

This code assumes there are no null values in the `Map`.

EDIT :

In Java 7 you can write:

```
for (Set<String> value : mMap.values()) {
    value.remove(productCode);
}
```

Comment: yes but I am writing this for an Android app I forgot to mention it sorry about it. But could you provide the same thing but without the lambda?

Comment: @user3182266 sure

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over all map entries, mutating the value for each:

```
map.forEach((k, v) -> v.remove(productCode)};
```

Answer (score 0):

using java 8 and lambda expressions

```
map.forEach((key, value) -> value.remove(productCode));
```